# How to use a special formula in Magento cart

Tags: php, magento

Please suppose:
Row product price = $1.5;
Quantity = 3;

Instead of total amount $4.5, it should be different amount based on finished product criteria.

Using configurable product options/attributes, my product page can display its finished product price correctly based on a special formula (written in JS).

Though I can calculate correctly using JS function (formula) on product page, I can't display its calculated amount on shopping cart page. How can I pass the calculated amount to shopping cart page so that its calculation persists in rest of steps in checkout?

Comment: As per my understanding about your question. You add the custom option in the product. On frontend when user select these custom option then you are calculating price by your Custom JS function. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, there are few superattributes, custom options. Depending on them, the custom JS function can calculate it correctly. Please note that formula is somewhat complex and cumulative, and stored in database for each product.

Comment: can you show me your Custom JS function here?

Comment: I guess you mean a custom tier price dependent on product options or quantity? Check this extension - http://www.itoris.com/magento-product-price-formula.html. You can create a formula like this: row_total = {price} * {qty} + {option1} - {option2} * k, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an observer when adding products to cart, based on the same logic (options and quantity) as your JS function.

You have to build an observer that catches the add-to-cart event `sales_quote_add_item` and put your logic there. You can define the product price with

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->setOriginalCustomPrice([your price])
```

This price will be saved to the quote object and persists in other steps in checkout.

If you want to calc the row total separate from price per item, you have to overwrite the `calcRowTotal()` method from the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class like explained here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/220715/

Comment: Good answer! Your answer is guiding how to change product price, though I need to customize its total amount using the formula instead! The product price will be displayed as original. For that, which method should I use instead of setOriginalCustomPrice()?

Comment: It generates Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in ..\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php on line 744

Comment: I re-wrote calcRowTotal() in a new class extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item. This method works if I add new product to shopping cart. But, it can't update subtotal in shopping cart page while updating its quantity.